# Is there a way to change the Trumbowyg editor background?

Tags: jquery, trumbowyg

I have some text in boxes where the text is supposed to be white.

This makes the text white in the WYSIWYG as well. Might seem straightforward but the WYSIWYG text box also has white background default so the box looks empty.

Is there a way to change the WYSIWYG editor background to the background that is most commonly used for transparant images? Or what would the correct approach be to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a chess-pattern to the background of the editor did the trick for me.

I generated the pattern using [patternify](http://www.patternify.com/)
which gives me something like this to add to my css:

```
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAHElEQVQYV2NkYGAwZmBgOMsABYwwBjYBsEoMFQBQhgIF9JIf4wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) repeat;
```